# RXSwift - takeUntil canceling before next event

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, rx-swift, reactivex

Following a similar example to question 39 here: http://reactivex.io/learnrx/

I'm trying to transform a method call `search(query: String)` into a sequence of those calls.
They way I'm achieving this is by creating a `Variable` which I update with the `query` value every time 
the `search(query: String)` method is called.

Then I have this in my `init()`:

```
_ = queryVariable.asObservable().flatMap({ query -> Observable<[JSON]> in
    return self.facebookSearch(query).takeUntil(self.queryVariable.asObservable())
}).subscribeNext({ result in
    if let name = result[0]["name"].string {
        print(name)
    } else {
        print("problem")
    }
})
```

If I type `"ABC"`, my `search(query: String)` method will be called 3 times with `"A"`, `"AB"`, `"ABC"`.
That would be mapped to `seq(["A", "AB", "ABC"])` with `queryVariable.asObservable()`.
Then I'm mapping it to Facebook searches (searching people by their names on Facebook).
And with `subscribeNext` I print the name.
If I don't use the `takeUntil`, it works as I'd expect, I get 3 sets of results, one for each of my queries(`"A"`, `"AB"`, `"ABC"`).

But if I type fast (before Facebook has time to respond to the request), I'd want only one result, for the query `"ABC"`. That's why I added the `takeUntil`. With it I'd expect the `facebookSearch(query: String)` call to be ignored when the next `query` comes in, but it is being canceled for the current query, so with this `takeUntil` I end up printing nothing.

Is this a known issue or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I used your code and found two solutions to your problem:

**1. Use `flatMapLatest`**

You can just use `flatMapLatest` instead of `flatMap` and `takeUntil`. `flatMapLatest` only returns the results of the latest search request and cancels all older requests that have not returned yet:

```
_ = queryVariable.asObservable()
    .flatMapLatest { query -> Observable<String> in
        return self.facebookSearch(query)
    }
    .subscribeNext {
        print($0)
    }
```

**2. Use `share`**

To make your approach work you have to share the events of your `queryVariable` Observable when you also use it for `takeUntil`:

```
let queryObservable = queryVariable.asObservable().share()

_ = queryObservable
    .flatMap { query -> Observable<String> in
        return self.facebookSearch(query).takeUntil(queryObservable)
    }
    .subscribeNext {
        print($0)
    }
```

If you do not share the events, the `searchQuery.asObservable()` in `takeUntil` creates its own (duplicate) sequence. Then when a new value is set on the `searchQuery` Variable it immediately fires a Next event in the takeUntil() sequence and that cancels the facebookSearch results.

When you use `share()` the sequence in `takeUntil` is observing the same event as the other sequence and in that case the `takeUntil` sequence handles the Next event after the facebookSearch has returned a response.

IMHO the first way (flatMapLatest) is the preferred way on how to handle this scenario.

Comment: But I'm not canceling the entire sequence, I'm using takeUntil only on that specific facebookSearch. Just like exercise 39. What's the difference here?

Comment: Also, if instead of a Variable I use PublishSubject<String>, the takeUntil works as I described. But I really don't understand the difference.

Comment: OK, I had a look at example 39. I'll add the difference between the example and your code to the answer.

Comment: I had a deeper look into the example and played around with your code to reproduce the problem you are facing. Turned out my first answer was not really spot on so I rewrote it from scratch.

Comment: Even if I user let x = queryVariable.asObservable() and pass x to takeUntil, it also doesn't work (in this case it is not a duplicate right?)

Comment: I don't understand why I need the share, but I'll accept your answer, because flatMapLatest is even better than having another takeUntil call. Also, just for the record, takeUntil works with PublishSubject<String>(). I ended up using this with your flatMapLatest suggestion (didn't test with Variable per se).